# How to read data from IO into data-structure and then process the data-structure?

Tags: haskell

first off sorry for doing the typical thing of 'where do I begin', but I'm totally lost.

I've been reading the 'Learn you a haskell for great good' site for what feels like an age now (pretty much half a semester.  I'm just about to finish the 'Input and Output' chapter, and I still have no clue how to write a multi line program.

I've seen the do statement, and that you can only use it to concat IO actions into a single function, but I can't see how I'm gonna go about writing a realistic application.

Can someone point me in the right direction.

I'm from a C background, and basically I'm using haskell for one of my modules this semester at uni, I want to compare C++ against haskell (in many aspects).  I'm looking to create a series of searching and sorting programs so that I can comment on how easy they are in the respective languages versus their speed.

However, I'm really starting to loose my faith in using Haskell as its been six weeks, and I still have no idea how to write a complete application, and the chapters in the site I'm reading seem to be getting longer and longer.

I basically need to create a basic object which will be stored in the structure (which I know how to do), more what I'm struggling with is, how do I create a program which reads data in from some text file, and populates the structure with that data in the first place, then goes on to process it.  As haskell seems to split IO and other operations and it won't just let me write multiple lines in a program, I'm looking for something like this:

```
main = data <- getContent
       let allLines = lines data
       let myStructure = generateStruct allLines
       sort/search/etc
       print myStructure
```

how do I go about this?  any good tutorials which will help me get going with realistic programs?

-A

Comment: Obligatory link: http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/ just in case this was bypassed -- "Gentle" is relative, of course.

Comment: I'm learning me a haskell for great good also, only a few days in though.

Comment: In addition to needing to use `do` notation or drop the assignment (`<-`) and move to using bind (`>>=`), you can't name something `data` as that is a reserved word.

Comment: Haskell is definitely hard to learn, especially for people with prior programming experience in an imperative language.  It *is* possible to write real applications; everything is "inside out" from how you are used to thinking.  Stick with it!

Comment: It sounds like you need a prescription for #haskell, thrice weekly for a month.

Comment: You may find http://book.realworldhaskell.org/ to be useful, the examples are a bit closer to representing real programs, particularly when coming from an imperative language.

Answer (score 10):

You mentioned seeing `do` notation, now it's time to learn how to use `do`.  Consider your example `main` is an `IO`, you should be using do syntax or binds:

```
main = do
  dat <- getContent
  let allLines = lines dat
      myStructure = generateStruct allLines
      sorted = mySort myStructure
      searchResult = mySearch myStructure
  print myStructure
  print sorted
  print searchResult
```

So now you have a main that gets `stdin`, turns it into `[String]` via `lines`, presumably parses it into a structure and runs sorting and searches on that structure.  Notice the interesting code is all pure - `mySort`, `mySearch`, and `generateStruct` doesn't need to be IO (and can't be, being inside a let binding) so you are actually properly using pure and effectful code together.

I suggest you look at how bind works (`>>=`) and how do notation desugars into bind.  [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710991/convert-do-notation-to-bind-function) should help.

Comment: note that from the academic standpoint everything including IO in Haskell is pure - the only side-effect is non-termination. However, it's common to say "pure/effectful" as synonyms to "non-monadic/monadic". To make learning purity even harder for newcomers, there is a function named `pure`.

Comment: @nponeccop using "monadic" as a synonym for "effectful" is not quite right and the fact people do it is probably a source of confusion for beginners. `IO` values are potentially effectful; `>>=` and other monad-related functions are pure but can have effectful arguments and/or results.

Comment: My opinion is other way around: I'd like everyone to stop talking about side effects and start talking about monadic code. Whether or not it represents "real" effects is irrelevant to programmers and only confusing. For example, ST vs State. Anyway, it's not a good place for an extended discussion

Answer (score 4):

See also [Explaining Haskell IO without Monads](http://neilmitchell.blogspot.com/2010/01/haskell-io-without-monads.html) by Neil Mitchell.

Comment: This is one of the two best "monad tutorials" I know of.  Very highly recommended.

Answer (score 4):

I'll try to start with a simplified example. Let's say this is what we want to do:

1. Open a file which contains a list of integers and return it.
2. Sort this list
3. Let's also reverse the list
4. Print the result on the screen

Let's also say that we have these functions that we can use:

```
getContent :: IO [Int]
sort :: [Int] -> [Int]
reverse :: [Int] -> [Int]
show :: a -> String
putStrLn :: String -> IO ()
```

Just so we are clear, I'll have a word about these functions:

- `getContent`: I made up this function, but if there was such function *that* would be it's signature (you can use `getContent = return [3,7,2,1]` for testing purposes). I'm sure you've seen such signature before and at least vaguely understand that since it does IO its signature *can not* be just `getContent :: [Int]`.
- `sort`: It's a function defined in Data.List module, usage is simple: `sort [3,1,2]` returns `[1,2,3]`
- `reverse`: Also defined in Data.List module: `reverse [1,3,2]` returns `[2,3,1]`
- `show`: don't need to import anything, just use it: `show 11` returns the string `"11"`; `show [1,2,3]` returns the string `"[1,2,3]"`, etc.
- putStrLn: takes a string, puts it on the screen and returns IO (), now again, since it does IO its signature *can not* be just `putStrLn :: Stiring -> ()`.

OK, now we have all we need to create our program, the problem now is about connecting these functions together. Let's start with connecting functions:

`getContent :: IO [Int]` with `sort :: [Int] -> [Int]`

I think if you get this part, you'll easily get the rest as well. So, the problem is that since `getContent` returns `IO [Int]` and not just `[Int]`, you can't just ignore or get rid of the `IO` part and shove it into `sort`. That is, this is what you *can not* do to connect these functions:

`sort (getRidOfIO getContent)`

Here is where the `>>= :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b` operation comes to the rescue. Now notice that `m`, `a` and `b` are *type variables* so if we substitute `m` for `IO`, `a` for `[Int]` and `b` for `[Int]`, we get the signagure:

`>>= :: IO [Int] -> ([Int] -> IO [Int]) -> IO [Int]`

Have a look again at those `getContent` and `sort` functions and their signatures and try to think about how they'll fit into the `>>=`. I'm sure you'll notice that you can use `getContent` directly as the first argument to `>>=`. So far what `>>=` will do is take the `[Int]` out `getContent` and shoves it into the function provided as a second argument. But what will be the function in the second argument? We can't use the `sort :: [Int] -> [Int]` directly, the next best thing we can try is

`\listOfInts -> sort listOfInts`

but that still has signature `[Int] -> [Int]` so that did not help much. Here is where the other hero comes to the play, the

`return :: a -> m a`.

Again, `a` and `m` are type variables, lets substitute them and we will get

`return :: [Int] -> IO [Int]`

so adding `\listOfInts -> sort listOfInts` and `return` together we will get:

`\listOfInts -> return $ sort listOfInts :: [Int] -> IO [Int]`

Which is exactly what we want to put as a second argument to `>>=`. So lets finaly connect `getContent` and `sort` using our glue together:

`getContent >>= (\listOfInts -> return $ sort listOfInts)`

which is the same thing as (using the `do` notation):

```
do listOfInts <- getContent
   return $ sort listOfInts
```

There, that is the end of the most terrifying part. And now comes possibly one of the *aha* moments, try to think about what is the result type of the connection we just made up. I'll spoil it for you,... the type of

`getContent >>= (\listOfInts -> return $ sort listOfInts)` is `IO [Int]` again.

Lets summarize: we took something of type `IO [Int]` and something of type `[Int] -> [Int]`, glued those two things together and got again something of type `IO [Int]`!

Now go ahead and try exactly the same thing: Take the `IO [Int]` object we have just created and glue it together (using `>>=` and `return`) with `reverse :: [Int] -> [Int]`.

I think I wrote way too much, but let me know if anything was not clear or if you need help with the rest.

Wha I've described so far can look something like this:

```
getContent :: IO [Int]   
getContent = return [5,2,1,7]

main :: IO ()
main = do
  listOfInts <- getContent
  return $ sort listOfInts
  return ()                   -- This is only to sattisfy the signature of main
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is a question of reading from `stdin` and writing a result to `stdout`, with no further intevening  user input -- as your mention of `getContents` suggests -- then the ancient `interact :: (String -> String) -> IO ()`, or the several other versions, e.g. `Data.ByteString.interact :: (ByteString -> ByteString) -> IO ()` or `Data.Text.interact :: (Text -> Text) -> IO()` are all that are needed.  `interact` is basically the 'make a little unix tool out of this function' function -- it maps *pure* functions of the right type to executable actions (i.e. values of the type `IO()`.) All Haskell tutorials should mention it on the third or fourth page, with instructions on compilation.

So if you write

```
main = interact arthur

arthur :: String -> String
arthur = reverse
```

and compile with `ghc --make -O2 Reverse.hs -o reverse` then whatever you pipe to `./reverse`  will be understood as a list of characters and emerge reversed. Similarly, whatever you pipe to

```
main = interact (unlines . meredith  . lines)

meredith :: [String] -> [String]
meredith = filter (not.null)
```

will emerge with the empty lines omitted. More interestingly,

```
main = interact ( unlines . map show . luther . map read . lines)

luther :: [Int] -> [Int]
luther = filter even
```

will take a stream of characters separated by newlines, read them as `Int`s, removing the odd ones, and yielding the suitably filtered stream.

```
main = interact ( unlines . map show . emma . map read . lines)

emma :: [Int] -> Int
emma = sum . map square 
  where square x = x * x
```

will print the sum of the squares of the newline-separated numerals.

In these last two cases, `luther` and `emma` the internal 'data structure' is [Int], which is pretty dull, and the function applied to it is idiot simple, of course. The main point is to let one of the forms of `interact` take care of all of the IO, and thus get images like 'populating a structure' and 'processing it' out of your head.  To use `interact` you need to use composition to make the whole yield some sort of `String -> String` function. But even here, as in the runt first example `arthur:: String -> String` you are defining a genuine function in something more like the mathematical sense. Values in the types `String` and `ByteString` are just as pure as those in `Bool` or `Int`.

In more complicated cases of this basic `interact` type, your task is thus, first, to think how the desired *pure* values of the function you will be focussing on can be mapped to `String` values (here, it's just `show` for an Int or `unlines . map show`  for a `[Int]`). `interact` knows what to "do" with the string. -- And then to figure out how to define a *pure mapping* from Strings or ByteString (which will contain your 'raw' data) to values in the type or types your principal function takes as arguments.  Here I was just using `map read . lines` resulting in a `[Int]`. If you are working on some more complicated, say tree structure you'd need a function from `[Int]` to `MyTree Int`.  A more elaborate function to put in this position would be a Parser, of course.

Then you can go to town, in this sort of case: there is really no reason to think of yourself as 'programming', 'populating' and 'processing' at all. This is where all the cool devices of `LYAH` kick in. Your duty is to *define* a mapping within the specific definitional discipline.  In the last two cases, these are from `[Int]` to `[Int]` and from `[Int]` to `Int`, but here is a similar example derived from the [excellent, still incomplete, tutorial](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Numeric_Haskell%3a_A_Vector_Tutorial) on the [super-excellent `Vector` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector) where the initial numerical structure one is dealing with is `Vector Int`

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8      as L
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed            as U
import System.Environment

main = L.interact (L.pack . (++"\n") . show . roman . parse)
    where 
    parse :: L.ByteString -> U.Vector Int
    parse bytestr = U.unfoldr step bytestr
    step !s = case L.readInt s of
        Nothing       -> Nothing
        Just (!k, !t) -> Just (k, L.tail t)

-- now the IO and stringy nonsense is out of the way 
-- so we can calculate properly:

roman :: U.Vector Int -> Int
roman = U.sum
```

Here again `roman` is moronic, any function from a Vector of Ints to an Int, however complex, can take its place.  Writing a better `roman` will never be a question of "populating" "multi-line programming" "processing" etc., though of course we speak this way; it is just a question of defining a genuine function by composition of the functions in Data.Vector and elsewhere.  The sky is the limit, check out that tutorial too.