# Convert a do block into a code that uses >>=

Tags: haskell, monads

I have the following function

```
foo  =
    do
    putStr "type in a sentence: "
    s <- getLine
    putStrLn ("You typed " ++ s)
```

I need to convert this function so that it does not use 'do' but uses >>= instead.

I was able to do that in other example where I have to concatenate 2 monads

```
maybeadd' x y = x >>= (\x' ->  y  >>= (\y' -> pure(x'++y')    ))
```

But I don't know how to do it in my case. Can someone point me to the right direction ?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a "do" notation with more than two actions to use the bind function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710991/convert-a-do-notation-with-more-than-two-actions-to-use-the-bind-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
foo = putStr "type in a sentence: " >> getLine >>= \s -> putStrLn ("You typed " ++ s)
```

The general rule is that lines without a `<-` desugar to `>>`, and lines with a `<-` desugar to `>>=` and a lambda.